# Postgres dump missing data when restored

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to restore a Postgres dump. I am using docker-compose to run a new instance of Postgres (same version used for the dump - Postgres 13), but when the restore ends, some data is missing. I also executed the restore multiple times on different PCs, but it seems to lose some data portions randomly. I am not getting errors from the logs.

The command that I have used to restore is the following:

```
gunzip -c dump.gz | docker exec -i image_name psql -U dbuser
```

Also, I have tried to extract the dump file and directly run the import via psql, but also I get randomly missing data.

Comment: Without the command you used to do the `pg_dump` or some idea what the missing data is or how you determined it is missing, this question is not going get anything but guesses as answers. Add the information as update to question.

Comment: I'm not sure, but it seems you are not catching the stderr output. Try `2>` for stderr only or `&>` for both stdout and stderr.

Comment: Your observation is correct, but running the command without redirecting the output to a file as well, I did not get errors

Comment: There is no way I'm going to download a 13GB(compressed) file and scan through it. The question still remains, what data is missing and how do you know?

Comment: I compared the databases restored on different hosts, and the number of rows is different

Comment: The dump command is `pg_dump` and the restore command is `pg_restore`. Any other command is going to be wrong, or do the wrong thing. So step 1: use the right tools. If you need to dump/restore with a docker container, either run your commands in the container, or expose your db port and run the dump/restore commands outside the container, with the correct `-h`, `-U` etc. flags

Comment: If I use `pg_restore` instead of `psql`, I get this error: `pg_restore: error: input file appears to be a text format dump. Please use psql`

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans your comment is incorrect. If you use `pg_dump` to do a plain text dump then you will need to use `psql` or some other client that process text to do the restore, as @mai_sicuel found out.

Comment: Number of rows in what is different? If you want an answer to this you need provide specific information about what you are seeing.

Comment: Every time that I restore the dump, the number of rows for each table changes. For example, I restore the dump, and table A has 1000 rows. If I clean up everything, start a new instance of Postgres and try again to restore the dump, the same table A will have, for example, 900, 850, 1100 rows. Could it be that Postgres has some sort of query timeout and therefore does not have time to enter all the data?

Comment: If postgresql self would have such critical bugs without even logging an error, nobody would use it. So whatever the problem is, it has to do with anything else involved in your case. You could compare the logs from restore, maybe you find some differences.

Comment: Per @Steeeve you need to look at the Postgres logs when you restore. Postgres will not truncate your data unless an error of some sort happens e.g. restore user not having sufficient privileges to add data to a table.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver looking at Postgres logs, I got a warning about increasing "max_wal_size". I did it, but I still have missing rows (I find a document where there is the expected number of rows for each table of the database)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I successfully restored the dump using the parameters described [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/183868). In detail, in my `docker-compose.yaml`, I put the following params:

```
...
services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    restart: always
    command: >
      -c fsync=off
      -c synchronous_commit=off
      -c full_page_writes=off
      -c wal_level=minimal
      -c autovacuum=off
      -c wal_keep_size=0
      -c archive_mode=off
      -c max_wal_senders=0
      -c maintenance_work_mem=3GB
      -c wal_buffers=-1
      -c shared_buffers=4GB
      -c checkpoint_timeout=20h
      -c max_wal_size=40GB
      -c min_wal_size=10GB
      ...
```